# Multiple where clauses in Ruby Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, where-clause

I am trying to create a search feature in Rails that allows the user to search posts using a keyword found in it's title, "materials list" or list of tags.

searching by title was simple and straight-foward. Adding ability to also search the "materials" associated table took research but I was able to come up with:

```
tags = Tag.where("tag_name LIKE ?","%"+params[:q]+"%").pluck("tag_id")

@searchResults = Post.joins(:materials).where("post.name OR materials.name  LIKE ?", "%"+ params[:q]+"%")
```

However, now I would like to add the tags table to the search. When I attempt the following method, I get an `PreparedStatementInvalid` error:

```
tags = Tag.where("tag_name LIKE ?","%"+params[:q]+"%").pluck("tag_id")

@searchResults = Post.joins(:materials, :post_tags, :tags).where("post.name OR materials.name  LIKE ? OR tags.include?(post_tags.tag_id)", "%"+ params[:q]+"%")
```

I have a table with a list of tag names and tag ids and a table with a list of post/tag pairs with no tag name. So I need to be able to take the query, search the tags list, grab the id, then use it to find the posts from post_tags table and return in the search.

Another approach:

```
tags = Tag.where("tag_name LIKE ?","%"+params[:q]+"%").pluck("tag_id")

@searchResults = Post.joins(:materials, :post_tags, :tags).where("post.name OR materials.name  LIKE ? ", "%"+ params[:q]+"%").or(where(tags.include?(post_tags.tag_id))
```

Comment: There is no `tags.include?(post_tags.tag_id)` in SQL land.

Comment: Note: Ruby is a case-sensitive language and capital letters have specific meaning in terms of syntax. Variables and method names should be lower-case letters. Capitals indicate constants of the form  `ClassName` or `CONSTANT_NAME`.

Comment: Is this with MySQL or Postgres? Postgres has array columns that can be indexed, which is great for situations like this. MySQL prefers a more relational table structure.

Comment: You might also be interested in https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on

Comment: @tadman don't go down the array column rabbit hole. Using a separate table usually a far better design.

Comment: @max Postgres has a fantastic `ARRAY` column type and with a `GIN` index it work exceptionally well.

Comment: @tadman there are cases where it's good choice but it doesn't work with AR associations, and it leads to either denormalization or no referential integrity. Also of you need to remove an inappropriate tag you need to loop through the entire table and manipulate the array on each row instead of just using a CASCADE.

Comment: @max It's not a good choice for associations, I fully agree there, but for something simple and non-referential like "tags" it works very well.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but perhaps something like this would work:

```
q_for_like = "%"+params[:q]+"%"

post_ids = PostTag.joins(:tag).where("tags.tag_name LIKE ?", q_for_like).pluck("post_id")

@searchResults = Post.
    joins(:materials).
    where(
        "post.id IN(?) OR post.name LIKE ? OR materials.name LIKE ?",
        post_ids, q_for_like, q_for_like
    )
```

I've assumed that `"post.name OR materials.name  LIKE ?"` is not working as intended in your original example, so change that if I was wrong.

Edit: also, perhaps post.id and post.name should be posts.id and posts.name .

Comment: Thanks. This was not quite the solution for me but helped. `PostTag` belongs to `Tag`, so  I needed to get a list of `tag_names` from `Tag`, then use those results and `IN(?)` to get a list of `post_ids` from PostTag, then created the following for search results: `Post.joins(:materials).where("posts.name LIKE ? OR materials.name LIKE ? OR posts.id IN(?)", q_for_like, q_for_like, post_ids). However now this repeats results multiple times for as many "materials" there are for each post.
`

Comment: Also, `post.name OR materials.name  LIKE ?` did work for me

Comment: The problem I'm expecting from `post.name OR materials.name  LIKE ?` is that the LIKE part is only being applied to the materials.name and not post.name; post.name will be true whenever the post has a name (any name). For the repetitions, perhaps look at `distinct`.